# problema al continuar conexion ftp con archivo bat

Tags: windows, consola, ftp

soy nuevo en la creacion de archivos.bat y por ahora tengo dos archivos el .bat para ejecucion del .txt que contiene la conexion y comando ftp para subir un archivo, pero en consola despues de que intenta subir el archvio me aparece un error 425, lo cheque y es un error de conexion, probe subir el archivo con filezilla y funciona bien, solo que ocupo el .bat y no se porque la conexion se cierra, probe poner modo pasivo pero es como si no lo reconociera porque al final usa el PORT que es el modo activo, y al final no sube el archivo

estoy usando windows 7 y el firewall esta desactivado, como lo mencione anteriormente ya use filezilla o el mismo explorador de windows y eñ archivo lo sube correctamente, pero desde el .bat no funciona

archivo1 ftp.txt

dominio.com

passcom

binary

passive

lcd C:\Backup1

cd www

cd respaldo

prompt

mput SG_Tecno_01-09-19-17-14-34.rar[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

archivo2 ejecutar.bat

ftp -s:texto.txt dominio.com

Answer (score 0):

debes hacerlo asi:
`ftp -i -s:ftp_conexion.bat`

contendio archivo `ftp_conexion.bat`

```
open dominio.com
username
password
passive
binary
lcd C:\Backup1
cd www
cd respaldo
put SG_Tecno_01-09-19-17-14-34.rar
```

> **nota:** recordar diferencia entre modo pasivo y activo y sus puertos:

[ftp conexion mode](https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/ftp/ftp-port-connection/)

Comment: gracias por contestar... el detalle sigue igual, a diferencia que me muestra el passive como 'comando no reconocido' me parece que lo lei en algun lado de internet, y me funciona si escribo 'literal pasv', y me muetsra una seria de puertos, solo que aun sigue cortandose la conexion